# Check if keyword in dataframe is present in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if certains keyword is present in another dataframe.
if the column in df2['name'] contain the keyword in df1['keywords'] then create a new column in df2 in each row that meets the condition with df1['app']

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'keywords': ['Excel', 'Agir', 'ILAB', 'GPO', 'DTAV', 'BI', 'Twin'],
                'app': ['Microsoft Excel', 'App Agir', 'Laborátório Digital', ' Gestão do processo', 'Digital', 'Painel BI', 'Digital']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Word', 'app Excel', 'Agir', 'GPO', 'Painel BI', 'Bob', 'Revit', 'Autocad', 'Acces']})
```

In df2 i need create a new column and fill with the matches results

for example, the keyword 'Excel' is present in second line of df2, so i want fill this line in the  column df2['new column']  with the row correspondent to keyword Excel in df1['app'], that is'Microsoft Excel

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`str.extract()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the keywords from `df2.name`:

```
keywords = '|'.join(df1.keywords)
extracted = df2.name.str.extract(rf'({keywords})')[0].values

# array([nan, 'Excel', 'Agir', 'GPO', 'BI', nan, nan, nan, nan],
#       dtype=object)
```

Then use [**`reindex()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to convert the `extracted` keywords to their corresponding `df1.app` value:

```
df2['new column'] = df1.set_index('keywords').reindex(extracted).app.values

#         name           new column
# 0       Word                  NaN
# 1  app Excel      Microsoft Excel
# 2       Agir             App Agir
# 3        GPO   Gestão do processo
# 4  Painel BI            Painel BI
# 5        Bob                  NaN
# 6      Revit                  NaN
# 7    Autocad                  NaN
# 8      Acces                  NaN
```